# Would you like to have the latex system more integrated?

Tags: discussion, mathjax

If you go to [this very good graphing website](https://www.desmos.com/calculator) the latex commands are already integrated. For example if I type in sqrt(x-1) ^(2y+3) +11/9y^2 it appears as $\sqrt{\left(x-1\right)}^{\left(2y+3\right)}+\frac{11}{9y^2}$ ( in fact I copied and pasted this after typing it on the website). Would you like to have this feature implemented? If so, how could we go about doing it? If this isn't a good feature, then this is just an advice from me on how to use latex to type in an equation that might take a while to type normally.

Comment: I don't understand. When you are typing an answer or a question, you do exactly this, though you wrap it in dollar signs, and the preview updates as you type. What's the advantage?

Comment: You can't, but on SE we would have two choices: either implement the integral (along with everything else) as well so that you could type "integral of f(x) dx", or put another symbol such as ## to tell the system that you want to manually imput latex

Comment: @Billy if you want to type in $\sqrt{\left(x-1\right)}^{\left(2y+3\right)}+\frac{11}{9y^2}$ you have to type: \sqrt{\left(x-1\right)}^{\left(2y+3\right)}+\frac{11}{9y^2} and then put it into dollar signs. But on that website you could just type sqrt(x-1) ^(2y+3) +11/9y^2 . If you put this between dollar signs, you get $sqrt(x-1) ^(2y+3) +11/9y^2 $ , not as pretty as the long version.

Comment: Oh, I see. Okay.

Comment: You really do not need to type in nearly as much as that for the desired result (no need for using \left and \right when the expressions do no require the parentheses to change size. And why would you want all those parentheses in that anyway. Anyway, implementing something like this would mean that it would be harder to write things that actually used a / or used the word integral. The current version is very familiar to anyone used to LaTeX which is a big advantage as a lot of the main contributors are.

Answer (score 5):

Desmos is an excellent graphing calculator, and the fact that it provides decent $\LaTeX$ markup generation (save for some extraneous `\left` and `\right`) is a plus. I can imagine the latter ability being useful to the someone making the transition from graphing calculator syntax to $\LaTeX$.

That said, I don't think it can or should be integrated with Math.SE in any way.

1. The $\LaTeX$-producing ability of Desmos  is limited to algebraic formulas. Entering integrals, matrices, sums etc. would still have to be done in $\LaTeX$.
2. With sufficient practice, entering  $\LaTeX$ becomes as easy as entering formulas in calculator format. Thus, most frequent users of the site would not need this plugin.
3. Neither Desmos team nor SE team is  likely to want this mutual engagement.
4. The site loads enough JavaScript into our browsers as is.